# two login panels with usertype and without usertype

Tags: php, parameters, default

I have two login panels- one with usertypes as radio buttons & an username & password and other with only username and password. I have written below function but its not working for me.

```
function auth_check_user1($login, $password, $agent=null )
{

$userAndPassValid = ($f['login'] == $login && $f['password'] == $password);
$userTypeValid = true;
if ($agent != null)
{
    $userTypeValid ==  $agent;

     $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' WHERE login = "' . $login . '" AND 
         password ="' . $password . '"  AND user_category ="' . $agent . '"  LIMIT 1';
     $r = $db->query ($query);  

     if ($db->num_rows($r)==1)
      {
       $f = $db->fetch_array($r);


    if ($f['login'] == $login && $f['password'] == $password && $f['user_category'] == $agent)
     $logged = TRUE;
    else 
     $logged = FALSE;
   }
     else
     {
     $logged = FALSE;
     }
}
 return $logged;
 }


 <input name="agent" type="radio"  class="radio" value="2" checked="checked" />
                  <label><?php echo $lang['agent_login']; ?> </label>
                  <input name="agent" type="radio"  class="radio" value="1" />
                  <label><?php echo $lang['homeowners'] ?></label>

                  <input   name="login" value="username" type="text"/>
                  <input   name="password" value="password"  type="password" />

                  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['Realtor_Login_menu']; ?>" />
```

Comment: This code is insufficient to give any answer. Please give your full code.

Comment: if $agent is null, $logged is undefined... and $f is undefined in the first line of your method.